# Recursively access deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

#### Problem Statement

I need to access a **deeply nested object**. I could've used a 3rd party util such as **[Lodash](https://lodash.com/)** but insisted myself on writing a **Vanilla JS** solution with a **recursive strategy**.

#### Code

Can this solution be **improved** with a **better** and **more efficient** approach? Is there any **edge case** which has been missed and could break the code?

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: "value"
    }
  }
};

const getPathValue = (object, path) => {  
  if (
    // ======= object checks ======= //
    object === null ||
    object === undefined ||
    typeof object !== "object" ||
    // ======= path checks ======= //
    path === null ||
    path === undefined ||
    path.length === 0
  ) {
    return undefined;
  }

  // key -> current key
  // rest -> rest of the keys in path
  const [key, ...rest] = path;

  // value of current key
  const value = object[key];

  // if rest of the keys are exhausted &
  // a value is found, return the value
  if (rest.length === 0 && value) {
    return value;
  }

  // as rest of key are not exhaused yet
  // in the path, keep traversing deeper
  return getPathValue(value, rest);
};

// ======= test cases with object edge cases ======= //
console.log(getPathValue()); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(null)); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(undefined)); // undefined

// ======= test cases with path edge cases ======= //
console.log(getPathValue(obj, [])); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(obj, null)); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(obj, [1, 2, 3])); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(obj, ["non exisiting key"])); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(obj, ["foo", "non exisiting key"])); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(obj, ["foo", "bar", "baz", "non exisiting key"])); // undefined
console.log(getPathValue(obj, ["foo", "non exisiting key", "bar", "baz"])); // undefined

// ======= normal test case ======= //
console.log(getPathValue(obj, ["foo", "bar", "baz"])); // value
```

Answer (score 2):

### Recursion

There are many reasons to avoid recursion in JavaScript.

- Recursion is an inefficient way to implement simple loops.

  Generally you use recursion to follow tree like paths where the path is dynamic or unknown, in this case the path is pre-determined and there is no need to stack the previous loop state as you iterate.
- A strong argument to NEVER use recursion is that JS has a limited call stack, but that same argument also means NEVER call a function (You may be at the end of the call stack) which is a ridiculous requirement.

  Until JS supports tail call optimization you should always use a loop in preference to recursion

### Argument vetting

The argument vetting too complex and can be simplified to  `typeof object === "object" && object !== null && Array.isArray(path)` see rewrite.

**Note** *"`null` is bad"* Good JS should never set a value to `null` and thus avoid the ridiculous need to test if an object is `null`, unfortunately we must deal with the designers of the DOM and CSS that seam to have missed what `null` means in JS.

### Cyclic safe

As a rule iterating paths should be wary of cyclic paths, however this is only a concern if the search is open ended (able to loop infinitely) and thus not an issue in this case.

### Inconsistent return

If passed an empty array your example returns `undefined` which does not make sense if compared to an incomplete path that will return an `Object` or `value`. An empty path is equivalent to an incomplete path.

For example the objects

```
const o1 = {A: { B: {C: 0}}};
const o2 = {B: {C: 0}};
```

The root object can not be found

```
getPathValue(o1, ["A"]);// returns {B: {C: 0}};
getPathValue(o1, []);   // returns undefined; One would expect {A: { B: {C: 0}}}
getPathValue(o2, []);   // returns undefined; One would expect {B: {C: 0}}
getPathValue(getPathValue(o1, ["A"]), []); // returns undefined; One would expect {B: {C: 0}}
```

### Rewrite

The rewrite

- Returns `undefined` if a path can not be found.
- Returns the object at the end of the path. eg `getPathValue(obj, [])` returns `obj` not `undefined`
- Will also follow an index path into arrays.
- Uses [?? (Nullish coalescing operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to simplify search along path and as such will return `undefined` rather than `null`. Fitting *"`null` is bad"* rule for JS.
- If second argument is not an array the result will be `undefined`.

```
function valueAtPath(obj, path) {  
    var i = 0;  
    if (typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null &&  Array.isArray(path)) {
        while (i < path.length && obj !== undefined) { obj = obj[path[i++]] ?? undefined }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Had `o1` been accessed dynamically with `o1[]` or `o1['']`, it would have thrown an **error** or returned **undefined** value respectively. So, respecting this behaviour, I expect `getPathValue(o1, [])` to return **undefined** likewise. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @VinaySharma An array with an empty string is not an empty array. What you return for these cases is up to you as there is no right or wrong. My view is... You do not provide a way to return the root object and thus would have to add a statement to the call if you required the root object. The function solves a path, if you take no steps along a path you in effect remain at the start (root) of the path. If you attempt to step on an undefined path eg named `""` empty string, then you have moved to an undefined location.